# Why does checking the result of an assignment operation work, but cant be combined with other conditions?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I understand that the assignment operator returns the value that was actually assigned, in order to make something like this work

```cpp
int a = b = c = 5;
```

And so expanding this concept, this is why it is possible (thought makes it difficult to debug) to write this code

```cpp
class A {
public:
  A();
  ~A();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  if (A* checkedA = new A()) {
    //this works just fine
  }
}
```

**However, my question is, why is it not possible to combine the result from the assignment operator with any other check?**

```cpp
  if (true && A* checkedA2 = new A()) {
    //this doesn't compile
  }

  if (true && (A* checkedA3 = new A())) {
    //parenthesis won't help
  }

  if (A* checkedA4 = new A() && A* checkedA5 = new A()) {
    //this will also fail
  }
```

On clang++ on my mac I get:

> ```
> ➜  Desktop  clang++ -c assign.cc
> assign.cc:14:15: error: 'A' does not refer to a value
>   if (true && A* checkedA2 = new A()) {
>               ^
> assign.cc:1:7: note: declared here
> class A {
>       ^
> assign.cc:14:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'checkedA2'
>   if (true && A* checkedA2 = new A()) {
>                  ^
> assign.cc:18:19: error: expected ')'
>   if (true && (A* checkedA3 = new A())) {
>                   ^
> assign.cc:18:15: note: to match this '('
>   if (true && (A* checkedA3 = new A())) {
>               ^
> assign.cc:18:39: error: expected expression
>   if (true && (A* checkedA3 = new A())) {
>                                       ^
> assign.cc:22:33: error: 'A' does not refer to a value
>   if (A* checkedA4 = new A() && A* checkedA5 = new A()) {
>                                 ^
> assign.cc:1:7: note: declared here
> class A {
>       ^
> assign.cc:22:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'checkedA5'; did you mean 'checkedA4'?
>   if (A* checkedA4 = new A() && A* checkedA5 = new A()) {
>                                    ^~~~~~~~~
>                                    checkedA4
> assign.cc:22:10: note: 'checkedA4' declared here
>   if (A* checkedA4 = new A() && A* checkedA5 = new A()) {
>          ^
> 6 errors generated.
> ```

And I also get similar errors with Visual Studio so I am thinking this is probably not a compiler conformance thing but rather a standards thing?

So, why is that? What is the reasoning behind it? I understand it can make the code a bit trickier to read (and maybe parse), but why doesn't even the parenthesis solve it?

Comment: Your first code sample never uses an assignment operator. In fact, none of these use an assignment operator.

Comment: @chris do you mean the int one or the first A-class one?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the very first sample. `int a = b = c = 5;` uses the only two assingment operators in this question.

Comment: Looks related to [Can a variable be defined only in the scope of an if-statement, similar to how it's often done for for-loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017216/1708801) basically you can either have a declaration or an expression but not both in an if statement. Unless there is a difference I am missing then it is probably a dup.

Comment: And http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour yes, you are correct, and this answer specifically seems to be the answer here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24017606/823653?stw=2

Comment: @chris, I am sorry for my noob-ism but how are the other A* pA = new A(); statements not assignment operators?

Comment: @codemonkey, They're using copy-initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider:

```
A* checkedA;
if (checkedA = new A()) { ... }
```

Here there is an assignment, and the assignment returns the value that was assigned, so that's why we can use the assignment as the condition for an if statement. However, in

```
if (A* checkedA = new A()) { ... }
```

there is no assignment occurring; instead what you have is a **declaration** of the variable `checkedA`, which is then **initialized** with `new A()`. The equal sign denotes *copy-initialization*, not assignment.

So the reason why this works *isn't* that an assignment returns the value assigned; in fact, what we have here is a **special case** that allows you to have a declaration inside the condition of an `if`, `for`, `while`, or `switch` statement. But it's only allowed if the declaration is the *entire* condition; that's why something like `if (true && A* checkedA2 = new A())` doesn't work.

In this special case, the value of the variable declared is converted to `bool`, and used as the condition. Elsewhere in the language, a declaration does *not* have a value and *cannot* be treated like an expression.

Comment: excellent clear explanation, thanks a lot mate

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't see (I had started typing my answer already)

Comment: May be worth to mention:  if checkedA2 was declared before the `if`, the expression `true && checkedA2 = new A()`  would be interpreted as `(true && checkedA2) = new A()` due to op precedence. Therefore I'd recomment to put extra brackets arount an assignment if mixed with other sub-expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (A* checkedA = new A()) {
    //this works just fine
}
```

The condition here is not using the assignment operator. It's actually a variable declaration with an initialiser. The standard has a special clause that says that if the condition of a selection statement (`if` or `switch`) is a declaration, the value of the condition is the value that that declaration gets initialised with.

```
true && A* checkedA2 = new A()
```

The problem with this is that it's not a valid expression. You can't nest a declaration within an expression. You could, however, declare `checkedA` before the `if` statement and then use assignment within the condition:

```
A* checkedA2;
if (true && (checkedA2 = new A())) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `error: expression is not assignable`. Parentheses are syntactically necessary, not just to avoid a warning.

Comment: @rici Oops, should have thought about it. Thanks.