# Direct-initializing an object inside a condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, initialization, c++03

It is possible to define and copy-initialize a variable inside the condition of an `if` statement :

```
if(int i = 17) { ... }
```

This also works with user-defined types, given that they overload `operator bool` :

```
if(Foo f = 42)      { ... }
if(Foo f = Foo(43)) { ... }
```

Why can't I use direct-initialization, like the following ?

```
if(Foo f(51)) { ... }
```

GCC emits `error: expected primary-expression before 'f'`.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57e93d0e82350720)

Is there a reason other than "because the grammar says so" ? And how can I work around it ?

I'm working with VC++03, where `Foo` :

- is a RAII-sensitive object, for which I took care *not* to define a copy constructor
- is a template taking arguments from the user
- has a two-parameters constructor

... so I'd rather avoid copying it or repeating its type.

Note : Although my actual problem is with C++03, I'm (academically) interested about answers in C++11.

Comment: Related to [Can a variable be defined only in the scope of an if-statement, similar to how it's often done for for-loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017216/1708801)

Comment: Why do you think the declaration `Foo f = 42` implies a copy/move? Shouldn't copy elision work?

Comment: @Columbo AFAIK copy elision is an optimization that maus or may not be performed, but even if it's not the object needs a copy constructor, which I've disabled to avoid `auto_ptr`-like evil. In the end I worked around the problem by passing an `std::pair`.

Comment: How did passing an `std::pair` work around the problem? You still need a copy constructor if it's copy initialization from a different type.

Comment: @bogdan Indeed. Now I'm wondering why it works.

Comment: @Quentin Hmm, I didn't know you disabled the copy ctor. Nevermind then.

Comment: @Quentin I tried it on GCC 5.1.0, `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic`, with a toy class with a private copy constructor and it didn't work on my side.

Comment: @bogdan Doesn't surprise me (MSVC 2008 here). Well I'll be happy it works and carry on :)

Comment: @Quentin Looks like it's a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795199/copy-initialization-bug) in MSVC. Even the latest 2015 version accepts the code. Sad, really.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++03, one could solely use the copy-initialization syntax:

> *selection-statement*: 
>          `if (` *condition* `)` *statement*  
>         […]
>
> *condition*:
>           *expression*
>           *type-specifier-seq **declarator*** `=`
>   *assignment-expression*

Since C++11, list-initialization was added:

> *condition*:
>           *expression*
>          *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq **declarator*** `=` *initializer-clause*
>          *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq **declarator
>   braced-init-list***

The syntax of direct-initialization, i.e. `Foo f(…)`, was presumably avoided for the same reason it was disallowed for non-static data member initializers: Ambiguities, in particular the "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 2):

Because the C++03 standard only allows assignment initialisation inside conditions:

```
condition:
    expression
    type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your restrictions, I believe in C++03 your only option is to declare the variable outside the `if` statement, adding braces for scoping:

```
{
    Foo f(51, 52);
    if (f) {
        //...
    }
}
```

In C++11 you could exploit braced initialization syntax:

```
if (Foo f{51, 52}) {
    //...
}
```